# Cloud based MSCRM non-production Development?

Tags: cloud, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, development-environment, production-environment

I have to do some development on our cloud based CRM 2011 instance.  Clearly, production edits are a bad idea.

As we have no development environment, I'd like to create a free 30 day trial of CRM.  How can I (easily?) load all current data and customizations from our production instance into the new trial to use as a dev environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you publish the same solution(s) to your 30 day trial that you did to your production environment (in the same order - remember, last in wins!) then you should have the same customizations applied (assuming your not making customizations on your live environment that aren't via solutions).

Then you can create a new solution on your 30 day trial and apply your required changes to the new solution (think of it like a patch). Then when you're happy, export it as managed (and unmanaged if you want to make any changes later on) solution and import it to your production environment.

Data is a bit trickier as there isn't a "export all my data" button. You can export all records for each of your entities through the export feature and [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328321.aspx) them, which is a bit painful, especially as some records likely depend on others.

Unless you want to go into a lot of custom code, this is the only way I know of to transfer data between organizations ([example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/23/transferring-data-from-one-crm-organization-to-other-organization.aspx)).